# JavaScript/Node.js: Why prototype.__proto__ = prototype instead of new

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm looking into the Express framework for node.js and all the inheritance is done by:

```
Collection.prototype.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
```

Isn't that equal to:

```
Collection.prototype = new Array;
```

Another one:

```
var app = HTTPSServer.prototype;

function HTTPSServer(options, middleware){
  connect.HTTPSServer.call(this, options, []);
  this.init(middleware);
};

app.__proto__ = connect.HTTPSServer.prototype;
```

Are there any benefits of those approches?

Thanks in advance!

Examples from:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/router/collection.js

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/https.js

Answer (score 1):

`new Array` invokes a constructor. setting `__proto__` does not. This is the only difference.

I presume the author was  <strike>too lazy</strike> did not want  to use `Object.create`

Comment: how does this have anything to do with jQuery?

Comment: I thought the use of `__proto__` was originally from the jQuery folks looking to prevent obvious collisions with other elements. Everyone else just agreed it was a good idea?

Comment: @JimSchubert I amended about 10 seconds too late :\ resubmitted the comment.

Comment: No, I was curious where the practice originated, that's the first time I can remember having seen it, was working in jQuery ... however, I think I've been corrected that that's an ENGINE thing, not a library thing, so there you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection.prototype = new Array;
```

Every Collection will share the same instance of Array.

I'm not sure whether this holds true with `__proto__` or not?